# How can I select the state from dropdown the place autocomplete address form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I currently have a working example where you can search for your address and it auto fills the form for you. I'm not quite sure how to get the state dropdown field also filled in without having to select it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField">
        <div class="selector"
        <span style="user-select: none;"></span>
        <select name="id_state" id="administrative_area_level_1">
            <option value="">-</option>
          <option value="1">Alabama</option><option value="2">Alaska</option><option value="3">Arizona</option><option value="4">Arkansas</option><option value="5">California</option><option value="6">Colorado</option><option value="7">Connecticut</option><option value="8">Delaware</option><option value="53">District of Columbia</option><option value="9">Florida</option><option value="10">Georgia</option><option value="11">Hawaii</option><option value="12">Idaho</option><option value="13">Illinois</option><option value="14">Indiana</option><option value="15">Iowa</option><option value="16">Kansas</option><option value="17">Kentucky</option><option value="18">Louisiana</option><option value="19">Maine</option><option value="20">Maryland</option><option value="21">Massachusetts</option><option value="22">Michigan</option><option value="23">Minnesota</option><option value="24">Mississippi</option><option value="25">Missouri</option><option value="26">Montana</option><option value="27">Nebraska</option><option value="28">Nevada</option><option value="29">New Hampshire</option><option value="30">New Jersey</option><option value="31">New Mexico</option><option value="32">New York</option><option value="33">North Carolina</option><option value="34">North Dakota</option><option value="35">Ohio</option><option value="36">Oklahoma</option><option value="37">Oregon</option><option value="38">Pennsylvania</option><option value="51">Puerto Rico</option><option value="39">Rhode Island</option><option value="40">South Carolina</option><option value="41">South Dakota</option><option value="42">Tennessee</option><option value="43">Texas</option><option value="52">US Virgin Islands</option><option value="44">Utah</option><option value="45">Vermont</option><option value="46">Virginia</option><option value="47">Washington</option><option value="48">West Virginia</option><option value="49">Wisconsin</option><option value="50">Wyoming</option></select></div>
        
              </td>
              
              <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
              
              </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALDabFHAnv2j865IAGR9HeNZ7sh3w7Bcc&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would definitely be appreciated even it is suggested that I use a jquery plugin that allows users to type data into the field and it selects from the best option in a list.

Its just at the moment I am not sure what the best option is to resolve this. Again, any help would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your select options have number as value. You need to change it to use two characters value because that's how it is returned.

So change your select menu's HTML to something like this in order to make it work with your code.

```
<select name="id_state" id="administrative_area_level_1">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Here is the fiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/t9kxmkzL/

Comment: That is awesome! I appreciate it allot. By the way, do you know how to combine the `street_number` and `route` into one field instead of two separate fields?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to combine them. I have created a new demo for that [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQPmWE). In that demo, the full street textbox will be filled only if both `street_number` and `route` are available.